# Got the error "Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in pages/"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I run `yarn build`

Got the error:

```
> Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in 
pages/

See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component for more info.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

My directory construction is:

- public
- src

  - components
  - pages

    - admin

      - index.tsx
    - _app.tsx
    - index.tsx
  - slices
  - utils
    ...
- .env
- .gitignore
- next-env.d.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- yarn.lock

I hope my way is correct.

What's wrong with my code?

**Update**

From Mark G advise and [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component), I recognized return value should be a valid React Component.

I thought return value should be valid JSX.

I think my return value is valid.

What's wrong???

`frontend/src/pages/index.tsx`

```
import LoginPage from "pages/admin";

export function Home() {
  return <LoginPage />;
}
```

`frontend/src/pages/admin/index.tsx`

```
export default function LoginPage() {

...

  function Redirect(to: any) {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
      router.push(to);
    }, []);

    return null;
  }

  if (logged_in.payload.loggedInReducer.logged_in) {
    return <div></div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        ...
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check to see if every `.tsx` file in your `pages` directory has an `export default` for the component.

Comment: Yes I did.  I shouldn't use it and use just `export` instead of export `default`?

Comment: If you did, keep it, because you need to use `export default` if they're meant to be pages. Did you visit [the info page](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component) mentioned in the error message? Maybe post the code from those files (in the pages directory) here so we can take a closer look?

Comment: Thank you for replying. you meant return value is valid JSX? I updated my question. I didn't find what wrong my code is....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `frontend/src/pages/index.tsx` file, change...

```
// missing `default`
export function Home() {
  return <LoginPage />;
}
```

...to...

```
// add `default`
export default function Home() {
  return <LoginPage />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you got an error, first check the file and the directory.

Here, You can see it's an error happening in pages/

as you have a file name index.tsx in pages, so it's the directory means pages/index.tsx (#Note: Whenever you import a directory it first checks is there any file name index.extension in this directory.)

In your index.tsx, you would have many functions. So, it finds a function which you exported by default.

Maybe you forgot to add a keyword **default** in the function of index.tsx.

In your **frontend/src/pages/index.tsx** file, just add a keyword default...
Hope it'll work and you can understand.

```
export default function Home() {
  return <LoginPage />;
}
```